# Laravel handling array of inputs

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-7

I have the following database:

```
id | name | age |
-----------------
 1 | John |  20 |
 2 | Jack |  29 |
```

I want to edit them all in a single form with the ability to "Add more" and then save/update as needed.
How is that achievable with Laravel?

My form currently is this:

```
@foreach($people as $person)
    <input type="text" name="name[]" class="form-control" value="{{ $person->name }}">
    <input type="text" name="age[]" class="form-control" value="{{ $person->age }}">
@endforeach
```

Then in Laravel I receive the `$request->all()` as follows:

```
  "name" => array:2 [▼
    0 => "John"
    1 => "Jack"
  ]
  "name" => array:2 [▼
    0 => "20"
    1 => "29"
  ]
```

Which I guess is expected, but not convenient to work with Eloquent.
What would be the Eloquent/Laravel way of doing this?

**Note:** In the real world example I'm developing `Name` is unique.

Using Laravel 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the user id to identify every row of results

```
@foreach($people as $person)
    <input type="text" name="users[$person->id][name]" class="form-control" value="{{ $person->name }}">
    <input type="text" name="users[$person->id][age]" class="form-control" value="{{ $person->age }}">
@endforeach
```

You would get the request as follows:

```
[
    "users" => [
        1 => [
            'name' => 'John',
            'age' => 20
        ],
        2 => [
            'name' => 'Jack',
            'age' => 29
        ]
    ]
]
```

Comment: Just to add on to what Lloople said, add rules too for unique names in the controller.

Comment: Why should be the name unique? There are three people called `John` at my office.